# Appending a variable to RSS link url

Tags: permalinks, rss

I have a rss feed for my demo blog here.

http://clickquickcash.com/feed/?user=john

It passes the 'user' variable 'john' into the feed posts.

I need to add the 'user' variable to the link.

Note - I had to replace my domain with 'websiteurl' below as this site wouldn't let me post more than 1 link as new user

websiteurl/this-is-a-test-2/

becomes...

websiteurl/this-is-a-test-2/john
websiteurl/this-is-a-test-2?user=john

Please can someone tell me what I need to change in the function.php or feed.php files.

Thanks

Comment: How does your site pass "the 'user' variable 'john' into the feed posts" Post that code, please.

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('feed_link','my_site_feed', 10, 2);
function my_site_feed($url, $feed_type ){
    $user = my_get_the_username(); //this function should return the username.
    return add_query_arg( array('user' => $user ), $url );
}
```

And get your rss feed url using:

```
echo get_bloginfo('rss2_url');
```

or

```
bloginfo('rss2_url');
```

Comment: Thanks - but I John is a variable. I added the following code - WILL IT WORK?                                              add_filter( 'query_vars', 'addnew_query_vars', 10, 1 );
function addnew_query_vars($vars)
{   
    $vars[] = 'user'; // var1 is the name of variable you want to add       
    return $vars;
}


add_filter('feed_link','my_site_feed', 10, 2);
function my_site_feed($url, $feed_type ){
    return add_query_arg( array('user' => '$vars' ), $url );
}

Comment: I don't think you need to filter query_vars and at any rate, that's the wrong filter ;) if `John` is a variable then you just need to add it within the `my_site_feed()` function. I've updated my answer to reflect this.